# How to properly wash a snowboard/ski tech jacket?

Tags: skiing, gear-care, snowboarding, jackets

I have a 10k mm waterproof jacket from Quiksilver and I was wondering if there is any supposed way I should wash it properly.

I know about Nikwax tech wash and have a bottle of it, but how much should I use of it?

Do I need to prepare or clean the washing machine before (from other detergents and residue) and what setting should I put it on?

Do i need to use 1k spin centrifuge? What sensitivity should I pick, a more harsh like cotton or something more easier like wool? Should I dry hang?

Comment: What's the jacket made of?

Comment: I have this model http://www.quiksilver.com/mission-plain-10k-snow-jacket-EQYTJ03016.html.

The other jacket I have said 100% polyester, but it also had 50% down and 50% something else which I do not remember what it was and it is not at my home at this moment. I will check it when I will get to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that appears to be made of "Dry Flight 10K" whatever that is... o_O I can't find any washing instructions for this...whatever it is

Reading between the lines a little I'm guessing it's breathable in which case I'd follow the below instructions:

- Thoroughly clean your washing machine and remove residues (I alwasy
  run a rinse though first)
- Wash with a non-detergent cleaner like [NikWax tech wash](http://www.nikwax.com/en-gb/products/productdetail.php?productid=4)
- The Jacket should have **labels telling you what temperature,Spin cycle, etc.** to wash on, see this [key of symbols](http://www.textileaffairs.com/lguide.htm) wash it following these instructions
- While its wet re-proof it using a water proofing agent (I prefer spray on ones as I find they work better, something like [NikWax Tx Direct](https://www.cotswoldoutdoor.com/p/nikwax-tx-direct-spray-on-300ml-E9714007.html?channable=e15806.MjQzMzdfMTgw&colour=180&gclid=Cj0KCQiAkNfSBRCSARIsAL-u3X8ihsTyo_D0KaB2toXEmtgrFk12NoU0-AC8SQmCNgrrfQ7C7vtjuh8aAmIUEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)
- If you can tumble dry your coat, check the label again:
  [image]
  ..do so. Tumble drying will aid the proofer attaching to the coat.
- If you can't tumble dry it line dry as usual

Comment: Two of these jackets seem to be the same on touch, however I guess the materials are a bit different. What I noticed is that on this one I linked it does not say specific cycle, on the other tho it says that it should be washed on the gentle cycle, does that mean that I should choose the lowest RPM even for the rinse cycle? Also, it says that I should rinse thoroughly, should I use more than one rinse cycles after washing it normally with Nikwax Tech wash?

Comment: Rinse thoroughly is usually just a euphemism for "rinse this". So a normal cycle should be fine.

Comment: What about RPM?

Comment: I've never seen this specified. Most washing machines just have a "cycle" which should match the symbol on your jacket. If it doesn't you'll have to check your washing machine instructions

Comment: One last thing (though if I find something weird on the other jacket, I will ask you for help if needed), I have one more Burton jacket that I noticed it says use powdered detergent only, why is that? Is it because they do not expect people to buy a Nikwax and powdered is better than liquid or anything else?

Comment: What they're getting at is you want a non-detergent cleaner (as mentioned above). A detergent breaks the DWR layer (I'm not sure why). Typically this is a powder, but the nik wax product is a non-detergent liquid cleaner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71460/discussion-between-appwizcpl-and-liam).